# Is there any way to warn or throw an error when parameters aren't deserialized?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Here is a scenario I faced last week:

I sent an array of JSON objects to a WebAPI method with a signature like the following:

```
void Post(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items)
```

An example of the JSON array might look like (I've removed most of the properties for brevity):

```
[{ size: 1 }, 
 { size: 1.5 }, 
 { size: 2 }, 
 { size: 3 }, 
 { size: 1.25 }]
```

The View Model was something like the following (most properties removed for brevity):

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

The problem was that ItemViewModel's Size property is of type "int" and some of the JSON object's size properties were of type "double".

WebAPI didn't see the objects as a match for the type ItemViewModel, but it failed silently and still deserialized the other objects in the collection, just ignoring the ones that didn't match exactly.

Is there any setting/configuration point or other way to have WebAPI throw an exception or log a warning when this happens?

Comment: Have you tried to validate against a JSON schema? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544183/validate-json-against-json-schema-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

First, the simplest, is to decorate your model with `[Required]` attributes and then call `ModelState.IsValid`. That'll tell you if something didn't deserialize right.

If you don't like going crazy decorating all your classes with attributes (I hate it), I hear good things about [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

You could also [validate against a JSON schema](http://vitalyal.blogspot.com/2013/10/json-schema-validation-in-web-api.html).