# Parsing multiple possible Json responses

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

I've seen a number of questions on here already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544183/validate-json-against-json-schema-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906220/deserialize-json-in-a-tryparse-way) but still not able to the following working.

For either of these responses which are in ex.Message:

**Response 1**

```
[
  {
    "validationErrorType": "WrongType",
    "message": "Validation error of type WrongType",
    "errorType": "ValidationError"
  }
]
```

**Response 2**

```
[
  {
    "message": "Validation error of type WrongType:",
    "errorType": "ValidationError"
  }
]
```

I am trying to dynamically parse this as follows:

```
JArray parsedJObject = JArray.Parse(ex.Message);

JSchema oldSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"
            {
                'type': 'array',
                'properties': {
                    'message': {'type': 'string'},
                    'errorType': {'type': 'string'}
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
            }");

JSchema graphQlSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"
            {
                'type': 'array',
                'properties': {
                    'validationErrorType': {'type': 'string'},
                    'message': {'type': 'string'},
                    'errorType': {'type': 'string'}
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
            }");

if (parsedJObject.IsValid(oldSchema)) // IsValid - 1
{
    // Do stuff
}
else if (parsedJObject.IsValid(graphQlSchema)) // IsValid - 2
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

However both IsValid() calls return true for either response. What am I doing wrong here?

For response 1, I'm expecting `IsValid - 1` to return `true` and `IsValid - 2` to return `false`

And for response 2, I'm expecting `IsValid - 1` to return `false` and `IsValid - 2` to return `true`

**Update**

Following the suggestions by [David Kujawski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4904297/david-kujawski) and [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) to loop through the JArray and add the `required` attribute I've made progress.

My updated code is below but still struggling with validating a schema with a nested `locations` object.

*Response*

```
[
  {
    "validationErrorType": "WrongType",
    "locations": [
      {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 1
      }
    ],
    "message": "Validation error of type WrongType",
    "errorType": "ValidationError"
  }
]
```

*Schema Definition:*

```
JSchema graphQlSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"
    {
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': 
        {
            'validationErrorType': {'type': 'string'},
            'locations':           
                {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': 
                    {
                        'line':   {'type': 'string'},
                        'column': {'type': 'string'}
                    }
                },
            'message':             {'type': 'string'},
            'errorType':           {'type': 'string'}
        },
        'additionalProperties': false,
        'required': ['message', 'errorType', 'validationErrorType', 'locations']
    }");
```

*Parsing response*

```
JArray parsedJObject = JArray.Parse(ex.Message);

foreach (JToken child in parsedJObject.Children())
{
    if (child.IsValid(graphQlSchema)) // Not resolving to true
    {
        var graphQlSchemaDef = new[] 
                        {
                            new
                            {
                                validationErrorType = string.Empty,
                                locations = new
                                    {
                                        line = string.Empty,
                                        column = string.Empty
                                    },
                                message = string.Empty,
                                errorType = string.Empty
                            }
                        };

        var exceptionMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(ex.Message, graphQlSchemaDef);

        foreach (var message in exceptionMessages)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are similar. only *validationErrorType* can be null

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Property *validationErrorType* is a string, string is a reference type and can be *null*

Comment: A concrete class containing all 3 properties is enough. *validationErrorType* will be sometimes null.

Comment: For `graphQlSchema`, try marking `validationErrorType` as required, as shown in https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties.  Json,NET schema seems to support this as shown by the docs: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema_Required.htm

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, but I was on holiday until today. I've made progress adding the required attribute and looping through the JArray as per David Kujawski reply. I've updated the question with the changes I've made to leave with with one issue related to nested objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the JArray vs JObject.  If you really want to process ex.Message as an array, then you need to loop through the children of the array.  Also, change your JsonSchema from "array" to "object".  The following works as you described:

```
        JArray parsedJObject = JArray.Parse(ex.Message);

        JSchema oldSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"
        {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'message': {'type': 'string'},
                'errorType': {'type': 'string'}
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
        }");

        JSchema graphQlSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"
        {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'validationErrorType': {'type': 'string'},
                'message': {'type': 'string'},
                'errorType': {'type': 'string'}
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
        }");

        foreach (var item in parsedJObject.Children())
        {
            if (item.IsValid(oldSchema)) // IsValid - 1
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
            else if (item.IsValid(graphQlSchema)) // IsValid - 2
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
```