# Validate expected json structure in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have some wpf app where I store data based on user's input in some local json file. roughly it looks something like:

```
{
  "Database": {
    "instance": "",
    "userName": "",
    "password": "",
  },
       "Website": {
    "ip": "111.111.111.111",
    "port": "8080"
  },
       "User": [],
  "ReportService": {
    "instance": "fff",
    "ip": "111.111.121.212",
    "port": "88"
  }
}
```

suppose I have an "Import" button witch let the user to import other json file.

My question is how to verfity that the imported json file has same structure as mine?

I mean same objects with the fields like username,password,...

Because I want to validate the imported json to verify that he has the same structure as I expect.

**Edit:**

My solution for now is `try, catch` but I'm sure that there is more elegant solution

Comment: Why not import the user JSON and test the resulting object?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544183/validate-json-against-json-schema-c-sharp

Comment: @ThomasD. can't see how it helps. plz post answers

Comment: you want to validate a given json, so you have basically two options: Either you implement a parser/validator yourself (which it looks to me you don't want to - which i totally understand) or you could use some 3rd party stuff for your validation. The link from me shows a take on with JSON schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas pointed out, defining your own [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) for your objects is the way to go. Then you can validate the imported files against this schema e.g. using Json.NET as shown [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm), since this library is usually the go-to choice for working with JSON on .NET

Comment: Just to note, Json.NET Schema may not be free, depending on your use case, as outlined [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/store/jsonschema).

Answer (score 1):

Specifiy object and then serialize and deserialize to it instead of JObject in JSON.net. so if the deserialization won't work you will be sure schema is changed