# Microsoft adaptive card

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to send an adaptive card to Microsoft teams channel via SMTP.
I am trying to pass Json through the string in c# via SMTP and send mail directly to the team's channel

```
 string Message = @"{
'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
'body': [
    {
        'type': 'Container',
        'items': [
            {
                'type': 'TextBlock',
                'text': 'Test',
                'color': 'Attention',
                'wrap': true
            }
        ],
        'bleed': true
    }
],
'$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
'version': '1.0'}";
```

`_emailSender.SendEmailAsync("abct@apac.teams.ms", user.Email, "Title", Message);`

Comment: What issue you found there? Include your code on your question.

Comment: You most likely want to validate that json against its schema [Validate JSON against JSON Schema C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544183/validate-json-against-json-schema-c-sharp)

Comment: BTW, that json is quite different to the one in the [MS adaptive cards sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots)

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes `"` instead single quotes `'`

You can paste this fixed JSON in [Microsoft adaptative designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer) and check the result.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Test",
                    "color": "Attention",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ],
            "bleed": true
        }
    ],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0"
}
```