# Validate request body against the json schema

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function (AF), that is triggered by Azure Service Bus messages.I have to validate the request body against the json schema in c#.I am new to azure and c#.Plz suggest.Is there any framework which can be used?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+validate+json+schema and top result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544183/validate-json-against-json-schema-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Few of the workarounds that you can try is to have [property Names](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names), The usage of "propertyNames" permits only properties with enumerated keys or those that follow a pattern.

Another workaround to use is to make the [additional property](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties) to false as @Ben suggested in the comments.

**REFERENCES:**
[Validating JSON with JSON Schema in C#](http://persianprogrammer.com/Education/Index/Validating-JSON-with-JSON-Schema-in-C-Sharp-#:%7E:text=Open%20Visual%20Studio%20and%20select%20a%20new%20project,JSON%20We%20will%20use%20Json.NET%20to%20validate%20JSON.)